# Wow64 subsystem and its implementation on x86_64

Tags: assembly, x86-64, privileges, memory-segmentation, wow64

I'm checking Wow64 subsystem on Windows 64 bit. As far I can tell on x86_64 processors, in order to run 32-bit applications, it leverages on Long mode compatibility sub-mode. Any system call from 32-bit compatibility mode is handled via a switch mode from current mode to 64 bit mode (switching the `CS` register from `0x23` selector to `0x33` selector).

I have a pair of questions.

The first is that under [x32dbg](https://x64dbg.com/) I cannot see the ntdll 64 bit version loaded in the process's address space.

The second is more general regarding the way the CPU (or actually the CPU cores) performs privilege checks on segment selectors being loaded into segment registers. For instance on far jumps (as in the case of Wow64 transition) the CPU implicitly need to load the new segment code selector `0x33` into the `CS` register. From Intel SDM it performs a check based on the `CPL` of the code selector currently loaded in `CS` and the `RPL` of the new code segment selector being loaded in `CS` (`0x33`) against the `DPL` of the associated code segment descriptor from in-memory GDT table.

My question is: which other type of checks are performed by CPU/cores during operations that (implicitly or explicitly) access memory in those segments ? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On modern x86(-64) OSes, segments are only used as much as required by the ISA. And for CS, for setting the current mode and privilege level.  Not for memory protection.

---

With a flat memory model, CS and DS base = 0 and limit = unlimited, so each "segment" covers all of virtual address space, i.e. segmentation isn't used for memory protection, only for user vs. kernel mode.

The only checking that's relevant is when reloading a segment register (e.g. during a far jump, or on `mov ds, eax`).  **Access checking during each load or store in 64-bit mode is just paging.**

In 64-bit mode, hardware requires a flat memory model; the base and limit are ignored for CS/DS/ES/SS.  In 32-bit legacy mode, mainstream OSes were doing that anyway for years before AMD64.  In compat mode, I think non-zero DS / CS / ES / SS bases are possible, but again mainstream OSes don't use them.  (CPU hardware special-cases base=0 to simplify address calculations in the AGUs in load/store units.  They might still do limit checking, but it always passes when limit=-1 with units of 4K.)

FS and GS segments can still have a non-zero segment base in long mode, used for thread-local storage (TLS). I forget if they can have a limit. (https://wiki.osdev.org/Segmentation).  You set their base to a value wider than 32 bits via `wrmsr`, and newer CPUs have `wrfsbase` / [`wrgsbase`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/wrfsbase:wrgsbase) which the OS can let user-space use to change the bases without a system call.  (Unfortunately these instructions only work in 64-bit mode, not in compat sub-mode of long mode.)

Comment: The segment bases for FS and GS are configured through a pair of MSRs, not through the segment shadow registers.  The content of the registers is ignored.  On recent CPUs, you can use `wrfsbase` and `wrgsbase` to directly configure the segment base.

Comment: @fuz: Good point, my phrasing shouldn't have said "segment *register*", but rather just segment, since `mov fs, eax` isn't normally used.  If it works at all, the GDT format only has room for a 32-bit base.

Comment: @fuz as segment shadow register you mean the "hidden" part of segment register filled in from the corresponding GDT segment descriptor.

Comment: @PeterCordes so when there is a switch from compat mode to 64-bit mode is there also a switch of SS segment ?

Comment: @CarloC: Re: SS, I don't think Wow64 has to change SS when doing a far jump to a 64-bit code segment.  With registers set properly, RSP in 64-bit mode will refer to the same linear address as SS:ESP in 32-bit mode.  Unless there's some stack address-width attribute that needs to be set differently for 32 vs. 64-bit mode, but I think AMD64 intentionally didn't give you the choice of less useful settings like 32-bit stack address size (ESP) in 64-bit mode, so hopefully no extra code is needed after a far jump for the stack to keep working.

Comment: @CarloC Yes, correct.  The segment shadow registers and the descriptor cache are one and the same thing.  Note that confusingly, some x86 processors had a separate segment selector cache to speed up segment reloads, but I think it was given up many CPU generations ago.

Comment: @fuz yet the GDT table entries continue to exist on x86_64 processors that fetch them into descriptor cache from memory (even though the segment base for FS and GS is configured through `wrfsbase` and `wrgsbase` other fields such as DPL continue to be configured by OS in each GDT entry and fetched from there into descriptor cache).

Comment: @fuz the same as above should apply also to fields such as DPL of segment descriptors cached in descriptor caches associated to other segment registers - e.g. CS/DS/ES/SS.

Comment: Btw, do `wrfsbase` and `wrgsbase` write only on the base address inside the descriptor cache (i.e. in the segment register "hidden" part)? In other words they do not update actually the corresponding in-memory GDT descriptor entries, I believe.

Comment: @CarloC: That's correct.  Updating memory would make them slower and introduce a lot of corner cases and problems, and nobody wants that behaviour. Like if you run them in user mode (CPL=3) and the GDT or LDT entry selected by the current `gs` register value is in memory that's only writeable by the kernel (u/s bit in the page table), should it fault?  Or what about when that virtual address isn't mapped at all, even if running in kernel mode?  What if it's outside the current table limit, if you ran `lgdt` since loading `gs`.  And should it skip the store when `gs=0` (the null selector)?

Comment: @CarloC: In 64-bit mode, `gs` and `fs` bases aren't normally set from a GDT or LDT entry at all (always via the MSR or via `wrgsbase`), so updating the GDT entry would be a total waste of time to have microcode decode the current register value and do all the checks.  Also, the GDT entry format only has room for a 32-bit segment base, but FS / GS bases are 64-bit values.  (Or maybe 48 or 57 bit if they have to be canonical.)  Also, it would be pretty insane if a user-space instruction could write the GDT with no checks by the OS, since user-space can set `gs` to different values.

Comment: @PeterCordes you said that in 64 bit mode/compat mode access checking for each load & store is done at paging level (through u\s bit in PTE entries). Nevertheless the check on `CPL` and `RPL` vs `DPL` continues to be performed upon loading either implicitly or explicitly a segment register, right ?

Comment: @CarloC: Correct.  OSes don't use segment limits, even in 32-bit legacy mode.  (That's why AMD64 could basically drop them without making it inconvenient for OS devs.)  Checking privilege-level stuff when loading a new segment selector is still a thing, but you normally never need to do that, except weird stuff like Wow64 far call from a 32 to 64-bit code segment.  (Other OSes have the kernel provide `sysenter` and `int 0x80` entry points so 32-bit libc works, and it avoids an extra mode switch between user-space and kernel code, straight from 32-bit user-space to 64-bit kernel.)

Comment: @PeterCordes so for example on Linux switching from usermode to kernelmode does not involve a code segment switch ?

Comment: @CarloC: yes, same for any OS.  You need separate GDT entries for ring 0 vs. ring 3 64-bit vs. ring 3 32-bit.  Setting a new CS is how you put the CPU into the right mode and privilege level. And yes the `syscall` instruction from 64-bit user-space (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/syscall) will change CS (from a selector set in an MSR), like `sysenter` from 32-bit user-space: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sysenter - note the `CS.Selector = IA32_SYSENTER_CS[15:0] & FFFCh` from an MSR value.

Comment: @PeterCordes but, since in-memory GDT entries are never loaded from there into segment register's descriptor caches (using instead the values from specific `MSRs` plus constants), which is the reason to have them in memory ?

Comment: @CarloC: There isn't a reason, that's why OSes set DS=ES=FS=GS=0, the null selector, for 64-bit processes (and I assume for 64-bit kernel mode).  Note that `mov gs, eax` *would* I think still load the internal segment state from the GDT or LDT if you used a valid selector (because tradition), it's just that software chooses not to do that because it's not useful.  You do need a valid SS and a valid CS for the machine to work, but the other segments work fine with the null selector; check with a debugger.  32-bit processes under 64-bit Linux run with non-zero DS and ES, IIRC.

Comment: @PeterCordes: ok, so an OS could just configure specific `MSRs` to get valid `CS` and `SS` selectors for usermode and kernelmode without build the corresponding descriptors entries in GDT or LDT. Then, as you said, for 32-bit processes the OS could setup only two 8-byte segment descriptors in GDT pointed by non-zero `DS` and `ES` segment selectors respectively.

Comment: @CarloC: No, only the FS and GS bases have MSRs.  No other part of any "descriptor cache" is exposed via an MSR number.  Also, CS itself is set with a selector from the IDT on interrupt (triggering the same stuff as a far jmp), so there has to be a valid GDT entry there for interrupt / fault handling to work, and for `iret` to work.  And SS from the TSS.